# Unable to login to console UI using PIM manager

Tags: database, db2, identity-management

**Context**

In an **ISPIM Appliance**, if appliance is up and running with all the three databases and its server as idb/esso/psr, I am unable to login to consoles using the 'pim manager'.

**Question**

Which privileges do I need to give to db2admin so that it can grant permission?

**I tried**

Give permissions using db2admin but its giving me error message:

> SQL0552N  "DB2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the 'Grant Permissions' section of [this documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRQBP_2.0.2/com.ibm.ispim.doc/installing/tsk/t_installing_db_server.html) page (or select your version of the software as needed).